# SQL: Select a product based on minimum value of key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to select **Category** with **lowest CustKey value** as seen in below table 1. I want it to be displayed in a column called **SignupCategory**. I have also linked to my current SQL code which I cant make display the Category rather than the CustKey. I appreciate any suggestions as I am terribly stuck atm. Code is semi-dummy code. Note: Given that I have 10.000 CustomerIDs I would want all 10.000 customers SignupCategory.

Table 1:

```
| CustKey | CustomerID | Category |
|---------|------------|----------|
| 1       | Cust1      | Paying   |
| 2       | Cust1      | Unpaying |
| 3       | Cust1      | Barred   |
```

Result should show SignupCategory 'Paying'

**SQL Code:**

```
Select c.AgreementNumber, SignupCategory

FROM Customer c
```

**Following is the WIP from another thread I found on stackoverflow:**

```
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT AgreementNumber, MIN(CustKey) As SignupCategory
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY AgreementNumber, Category) X
ON c.AgreementNumber = X.AgreementNumber and c.Category = TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar,X.SignupCategory)
```

**Following code works but displays CustKey (similar to what I found on stackoverflow):**

```
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT AgreementNumber, MIN(CustKey) As SignupCategory
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY AgreementNumber) X
ON c.AgreementNumber = X.AgreementNumber AND c.CustKey = X.SignupCategory
```

Comment: select category as SignupCategory from Customer where CustKey = (select MIN(CustKey) from Customer ) ;  --try this

Comment: Hi Ahmar,

Thanks for your answer!

It works but I need it for all customers. Lets say that I have Cust1 to Cust10000. I would want all 10.000 customers SignupCategory. 

Sorry for not clarifying beforehand

Comment: From your other quoted answer note that SELECT MIN(CustKey) as SignupCategory FROM Customer GROUP BY CustKey   lists the SignupCategory for all customers.  INNER JOIN Customer on that

Comment: SELECT category as SignupCategory FROM Customer WHERE CustKey IN (SELECT MIN(CustKey) FROM Customer group by CustomerID); -- for all customers respectively and if you have huge amount of data then use EXISTS instead of IN

Comment: Thanks both of you! It works like a charm. 

Much appreciated!! Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome. Posting the same as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all customers respectively and if you have huge amount of data then use EXISTS instead of IN:-

```
SELECT category as SignupCategory FROM Customer WHERE CustKey IN (SELECT MIN(CustKey) FROM Customer group by CustomerID);
```